# How do you compute the OPE coefficients for the contribution from the identity in a 2D CFT?

Tags: operators, conformal-field-theory, correlation-functions

Using the OPE expansion: [image] where p indexes primary fields, h the weights of the fields, and k the level of the descendants.

I want to compute the coefficients that come from the identity operator: [image] up to and including level 2. (This is in 2D CFT)

I tried to compare the OPE expansion to the two point correlator: [image]
but the result seems trivial? Don't you just get 1 for the first coefficient, and then 0 for everything higher, since the identity operator has weight 0?

Answer (score 2):

These computations are done in Section 2.2.4 of my review article https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.4290 . The coefficients you need can be extracted from Eqs. (2.2.58) - (2.2.60).

There are some subtleties due to the identity operator, whose $L_{-1}$ descendants vanish, and have ill-defined coefficients. Nevertheless, the coefficient of the energy-momentum tensor is unambiguous:
$$
f^{L_{-2}} = \frac{2h_1}{c}  \qquad \text{with} \qquad h_1=h_2
$$